# Application runs faster in a virtual machine?

Tags: c, linux, virtualization

I am working on tuning some server code for maximum performance, but I am getting some weird results. The server seems to run faster in a virtual machine than when run natively. Both setups are using the same hardware.

The server is written for Linux, and the test client is 100% standard POSIX. Both applications are written in C.

**Setup 1: (~300k request/second)**

- OSX 10.7.4 Host machine
- Ubuntu Linux 12.04 Server virtualized in VirtualBox
- VirtualBox has been set to use up to 100% of the host resources
- VirtualBox in bridge networking mode, Ubuntu gets it's own IP on the network
- Test client program running on OSX

**Setup 2: (~100k request/second)**

- Ubuntu Linux 12.04 Server Host OS
- Tester and server are run natively, connecting through localhost

The tester works by spawning 256 threads that all independently connect to the server and send commands. The server processes requests in pipelines, spawning only a number of threads equal to the number of available cores.

**Here are the possibilities I have come up with so far:**

- OSX scheduler is more efficient with handling the 256 threads from the tester program
- Virtualbox's network interface is more efficient than linux's loopback interface
- Virtualizing the server allows the scheduler to more efficiently divide time between the tester and server

I need to figure out what is causing the slow down, and what I can do to fix the issue.

EDIT for additional information:

- I don't have access to any other computers to run the tester on
- The server is similar to memcached, it doesn't access the disk
- 4 Core i7 - 8GB RAM (more than enough RAM for the tester and server (even in the VM))

Comment: Can you try running the tester client program on a different computer connecting to each setup over the physical network?  You can then try that two ways, one with the tester on OSX and the other with the tester on a Ubuntu machine.

Comment: I don't have access to any other machines powerful enough to run the tester. I tried running the tester on my laptop, but the performance is then bottlenecked by the laptop, so it's hard to make performance measurements.

Comment: Does your server access disk at all?

Comment: No. I should add, it is a memory only cache server, similar to memcached.

Comment: Did you try running it through a profiler to identify which code sections are executed faster or slower in each setup?

Comment: If you have much more threads than cores, all kinds of weird scheduler artefacts start to happen in IO-bound applications. This is actually not surprising.

Comment: I have run the server through a profiler, and it shows the expected result - a much higher amount of it's time is spent in the kernel when it's being virtualized. That's why I believe the scheduler is at fault  - the server seems to be doing less work when it is run natively, but the wall clock time is higher.

Comment: You forgot to describe the real hardware running (indirectly thru VMs) your program.

Comment: I added it, although I'm not sure how relevant it is because it's the same in both scenarios.

Comment: You may want to use `oprofile` or some other kind of global profiler (I hear Intel makes a good one).

Comment: How many cores are configured in the VM?

Comment: 8. The CPU supports hyperthreading.

Comment: Let's clarify. On real hardware the server uses one thread per core (and there's 4 cores with 2 logical CPUs per core) so the server has 4 threads; and inside the virtual machine (which is probably configured as 8 cores with 1 logical CPU per core) the server uses 8 threads? What happens if you tell the server to use one thread per CPU instead of one thread per core (would the server run much better on real hardware with 8 threads instead of 4)?

Comment: To clarify, I am using the function `sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN)` to determine the number of CPUs available - this will return 8 in both scenarios.

Comment: Does "requests/second" mean requests handled by the server per second, or does it mean requests sent by the testing program per second? I can imagine that these figures might be different, and that (for example) on real hardware the tester might be sending 900K requests per second and consuming so much CPU time that the server is only able to handle 100K requests per second (where there's an infinitely expanding FIFO buffer in the middle trying to cope with storing an extra 800K requests per second).

Comment: The tester waits for a response before sending the next request, so the numbers are one in the same.

Comment: I suspect your assumption about one thread per CPU core being optimal is simply wrong. It just performs better when virtualized. Try `2*sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN)` workers, for example. If the threads do any sort of blocking calls -- even thread synchronization -- then the optimum number of worker threads may be even higher.

Comment: There are 0 blocking calls in the server code.

Comment: I wonder why such a nice Q should be closed?